# Matching a column with other column based on JOIN Criteria

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

I am trying to get the Country name from the IPs that I have recorded within my CMS.

I have to show the country from the total number of unique visits that came to my site.

The output I expect would be something as follows:-

```
Country Visited | Total Visits
_______________________________

United States   |   482
Korea           |   213
Pakistan        |   123
Cuba            |    83
France          |    53
Netherlands     |    13
....
```

### What I achieved yet

So, I managed to show the Unique Visitors to my site in an aggregate fashion in the exact way I want through the following query:-

(Please see Appendix at the end of this post for Table Structure and Sample Data)

```
SELECT DISTINCT (
hostname
), COUNT( DISTINCT TIMESTAMP ) AS visits
FROM mslop_login_activity
GROUP BY uid, hostname
ORDER BY  `visits` DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

This gives me the output of:-

```
Hostname        |  Visits
_______________________________

157.191.122.36  |   482
72.17.66.44     |   213
157.191.118.26  |   123
157.191.153.16  |    83
157.191.199.32  |    53
157.191.121.49  |    13    

....
```

Hence I am grouping the same IPs in a table and counting their occurrences in a table. Hence this is basically counting the visits that came from the same IP.

Now, I would want to match these IPs to country so that I can get total visits from each country. That is exactly what I want.

### How I found the country based on IP

(All the table/data details are in Appendix)

```
   SELECT cc, cn
    FROM ip
    NATURAL JOIN cc
    WHERE INET_ATON(  "157.191.122.36" ) 
    BETWEEN START AND END
```

This gives me the output as:-

```
cc | cn
--------
US | United States
```

This is correct, as it's giving me the correct Country based on the IP provided.

This is where I am stuck, and stuck really badly. I need to show countries instead of IPs in the query I created above. Please help.

### Couple of considerations though:-

- An IP could be different for the same country, and one or more IPs could point out to the same country. We need to group the same countries IPs together and show the total no. of Visits (from mslop_login_activity table) in the query we make.
- The query has to go through the ip and cc, which contains thousands of records, hence hopefully the query is fast.

Please, please assist me in this, I'll be very thankful.

### Appendix (Structure and Data of the Tables)

### **mslop_login_activity**

(Structure)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mslop_login_activity` (
  `aid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'The primary identifier for an activity (session).',
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'The mslop_users.uid corresponding to a session, or 0 for anonymous user.',
  `host_user_agent` varchar(256) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT '$_SERVER["HOST_USER_AGENT"] string. This can be used with get_browser() in PHP.',
  `hostname` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The IP address that was used for this session.',
  `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'The UNIX timestamp when the session was started.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`aid`),
  KEY `aid` (`aid`),
  KEY `uid` (`uid`),
  KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`)
);
```

(Data)

```
INSERT INTO `mslop_login_activity` (`aid`, `uid`, `host_user_agent`, `hostname`, `timestamp`) VALUES
(1, 3, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0', '172.24.1.143', 1363038356),
(873, 4, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.59.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.9 Safari/534.59.8', '157.191.122.36', 1369773601),
(883, 83, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Tablet PC 2.0)', '157.191.122.36', 1369774959),
(893, 83, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31', '157.191.122.36', 1369818602),
(903, 83, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; GTB7.4; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Tablet PC 2.0)', '157.191.122.36', 1369838690),
(913, 83, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; GTB7.4; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Tablet PC 2.0; AskTbORJ/5.15.23.36191)', '157.191.122.36', 1369840224),
(923, 83, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0', '157.191.122.36', 1369841748),
(933, 83, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Tablet PC 2.0)', '157.191.122.36', 1370255417),
(943, 83, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)', '157.191.122.36', 1370258059),
(953, 83, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)', '157.191.122.36', 1370258060),
(963, 93, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; AskTbORJ/5.15.15.36191)', '157.191.122.36', 1370299827),
(973, 93, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; AskTbORJ/5.15.15.36191)', '157.191.122.36', 1370299852),
(983, 93, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.59.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.9 Safari/534.59.8', '157.191.122.36', 1370299899),
(993, 93, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.59.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.9 Safari/534.59.8', '157.191.122.36', 1370299920),
(1003, 93, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.59.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.9 Safari/534.59.8', '157.191.122.36', 1370299995),
(1013, 93, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36', '157.191.122.36', 1370319811),
(1023, 3, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36', '157.191.122.36', 1370319835),
(1033, 93, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36', '157.191.122.36', 1370319939),
(1043, 83, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36', '157.191.122.36', 1370320312),
(1053, 93, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36', '157.191.122.36', 1370320640),
(1063, 3, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36', '157.191.122.36', 1370320713),
(1073, 83, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36', '157.191.122.36', 1370363702),
(1083, 83, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36', '157.191.122.36', 1370363987),
(1093, 3, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36', '157.191.122.36', 1370364021),
(1103, 3, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36', '157.191.122.36', 1370364028),
(1113, 83, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36', '157.191.122.36', 1370365896),
(1123, 93, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36', '157.191.122.36', 1370366087),
(1133, 93, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.59.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.9 Safari/534.59.8', '157.191.122.36', 1370367070),
(1143, 3, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36', '157.191.122.36', 1370368567),
(1153, 3, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36', '157.191.122.36', 1370368575),
(1163, 83, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Tablet PC 2.0)', '157.191.122.36', 1370379345),
(1173, 83, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; GTB7.4; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Tablet PC 2.0)', '157.191.122.36', 1370427302),
(1183, 83, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)', '157.191.122.36', 1370503422),
(1193, 93, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.59.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.9 Safari/534.59.8', '157.191.122.36', 1370534329),
(1203, 83, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Tablet PC 2.0)', '157.191.122.36', 1370866207),
(1213, 83, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)', '157.191.122.36', 1370871353),
(1223, 83, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; chromeframe/26.0.1410.43; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Tablet PC 2.0)', '157.191.122.36', 1370877702),
(1233, 83, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36', '157.191.122.36', 1371015245),
(1243, 83, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Tablet PC 2.0)', '157.191.122.36', 1371069245),
(1253, 83, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)', '157.191.122.36', 1371117509),
(1263, 83, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36', '157.191.122.36', 1371137716),
(1273, 83, 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)', '157.191.122.36', 1371197327),
(1283, 83, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36', '157.191.122.36', 1371427531),
(1293, 83, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)', '157.191.122.36', 1371552899),
(1303, 83, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)', '157.191.122.36', 1371635304),
(1313, 93, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.59.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.9 Safari/534.59.8', '157.191.122.36', 1371770752),
(1323, 93, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.59.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.9 Safari/534.59.8', '157.191.122.36', 1371771394),
(1333, 3, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36', '157.191.122.36', 1371771647),
(1343, 3, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/536.26.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.2 Safari/536.26.17', '157.191.122.36', 1371772611),
(1353, 3, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/536.26.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.2 Safari/536.26.17', '157.191.122.36', 1371772626),
(1363, 3, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36', '157.191.122.36', 1371772931),
(1373, 93, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SIMBAR={37EF0ACB-CCB3-11E2-9611-E006E6BAE768}; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; AskTbORJ/5.15.15.36191)', '157.191.122.36', 1371782438),
(1383, 93, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.59.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.9 Safari/534.59.8', '157.191.122.36', 1371782562),
(1393, 3, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36', '157.191.122.36', 1371790767),
(1403, 83, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/536.26.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.2 Safari/536.26.17', '157.191.122.36', 1371834780);
```

### **cc**

(Structure)

```
CREATE TABLE cc (
        ci TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
        cc CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
        cn VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
        );
```

(Data)

Since it's large, you can download it through this link :-

http://d.pr/f/N3KT

### **ip**

(Structure)

```
CREATE TABLE ip (
        start INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        end INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        ci TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
        );
```

(Data)

Since it's large, you can download it through this link:-

http://d.pr/f/wcEy.

I apologize for this long post. Hopefully, it is clear.

Comment: i am trying to re-simulate your environment.
so to get it clear,you want your query to show you the Country Name instead of IP, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very much a guess because I'm not familiar with the `INET_ATON` function, but maybe it will lead you to an answer:

```
SELECT cc.cn
     , sum(a.visits) as total_visits
FROM (
   SELECT hostname
        , COUNT( DISTINCT TIMESTAMP ) AS visits
   FROM mslop_login_activity
   GROUP BY hostname
   ) a

JOIN ip
ON   INET_ATON( a.hostname ) BETWEEN ip.START AND ip.END

JOIN cc
ON   cc.ci=ip.ci

GROUP BY cc.cn 
ORDER BY total_visits DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Your original code was grouping by UID and HOSTNAME, which I changed to just HOSTNAME. Also, a "range lookup" join like this will probably not perform well.  There may be other solutions.

UPDATE:  Altered answer to summarize visits for IP addresses in the same country.

Comment: Thank you very much Bellevue. It is fantastic. Only small thing that I added sample new IPs from Germany, Netherlands and United States and it's not aggregating all of them. For.e.g. It is `United States | 131 - Netherlands | 12 - Netherlands | 2 - Netherlands | 2 - Germany | 1 - Germany | 1 ...` etc. What this is doing is that it matches all the similar IPs and convert them into countries. But what if there is a different IP which corresponds to the same country? It makes another row for it and lists the same country with a new number.

Comment: Hence my question is:- Could we combine all the different IPs which corresponds to same country and list all the total number of Visits without any country duplication?

Comment: @Steve See if the revision is what you need.

Comment: Wow! Bob, you just fixed something that was stuck for more than 3 days!!! Thank you so so much!

Answer (score 1):

one of the options: you can put the grouping query above in a subquery and then perform a higher level select where you calculate the country for each ip.

```
 select inner_table.hostname, 
        (select cn 
         from cc
         where ci = (select ci
                     from ip
                     where INET_ATON(inner_table.hostname) BETWEEN START AND END
                    )
        ) as country,
        inner_table.visits
 from (

    SELECT DISTINCT (
      hostname
    ), COUNT( DISTINCT TIMESTAMP ) AS visits
    FROM mslop_login_activity
    GROUP BY uid, hostname
    ORDER BY  `visits` DESC 
    LIMIT 0 , 30
 ) inner_table
```